# Partial Orders: transitivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I made a post earlier on partial order of subset but I am submitting a new question because I want to focus on one part in more detail because I really do not understand it.

This is the PowerSet example I had posted:

$P\{u, v, w\} = \{\varnothing, \{u\}, \{v\}, \{w\}, \{u, v\}, \{u, w\}, \{v, w\}, \{u, v, w\}\}$

I know  $\{u, v\}$, $\{v, w\}$, $\{u, w\}$ is transitive but I don't understand how it is in line with the definition of transitivity for subsets which is:

**If A⊆B and B⊆C, then A⊆C holds**

**However, $u⊈v$, $v⊈w$ and $u⊈w$, I mean...its clearly not...u is a different element to v, v is a different element to w...etc**

I am extremely confused by this, could someone please explain, thank you.

Edit: even if we use integers instead of letters like someone in the comments did:

P{1,2,3}={∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}
1 is not a subset of 2, 1 is not a sunset of 3 and 2 is not a subset of 3 so this doesn't make sense to me either

Comment: What you mean when wrote "I know $\{u,v\},\{v,w\}, \{u,w\}$ is transitive " ?

Comment: well using the normal definition of transitive I know it's transitive but I don't get the subset definition as you can see in my question @zkutch

Comment: Can you formulate exactly what you called "normal definition of transitive" for given case?

Comment: That's not really relevant to the question as my confusion lies with the subsets. But transitive means if both (a, b)∈R and (b, c)∈R, then (a, c)∈R but I am not confused with this, I am confused with the subsets @zkutch

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding when you claim to "know $\{u,v\}, \{v,w\}, \{u,w\}$ is transitive."  The word transitive can be used in connection with a relation, or in connection with a set, and perhaps in other ways.  But you will need to define what you mean by applying it to three sets.

Comment: What you wrote in comment is "R relation is transitive" and it is well known definition , but you wrote in question 3 sets are transitive - what it mean?

Comment: I don't know how the word transitive can be used in relation to a set, please check in bold in my question @hardmath

Comment: Well, clearly you are confused not just about transitivity, but about the power set itself. It probably does not help you to use letters $u,v,w$ for the elements of the base set, because then you are asking questions about *their* subset relations, which is not the point. Try using $\{1,2,3\}$ as the base set instead. Then you probably see that you are not supposed to be asking questions like $1 \subseteq 2$.

Comment: if we use P{1,2,3}={∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} that still wouldn't be true. 1 is not a subset of 2, 1 is smaller than 2 yes but not a subset of 2 @JukkaKohonen

Comment: Now of course you can use any three-element set as the base set, for example $\{\text{Bill}, \text{Mary}, \text{Spot}\}$ but the point here is that the elements of the base set are just "indivisible units". They just are. What you are interested in are *their sets*, like $\{1,2\}$ or $\{\text{Bill},\text{Mary}\}$. For studying this set structure it does not really matter what the three elements are, so you could as well use small integers.

Comment: But like I said before it still doesn't make sense. 1 is not a subset of 2 @JukkaKohonen

Comment: Please use the set braces to avoid confusion between elements and sets. Are you saying that $\{1\}$ is not a subset of $\{2\}$? That is true, but what is the problem?

Comment: I replied to your answer below but just to reiterate I meant 1 ⊈ 2 @JukkaKohonen

Answer (score 2):

Let use take the base set to be some small integers to avoid confusion. Also let us be careful to use the set braces when talking about sets, so that we are not confusing elements and sets.

Transitivity talks about *sets*, namely, subsets of the base set (or equivalently: elements of the power set). So *if* you have three such sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, *and* if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, *then* transitivity is claiming that also $A \subseteq C$.

Let us see this in action. But let us take a bigger base set so that it is at least mildly interesting. Let us take five elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Suppose, *for example*, that $A=\{2,3\}$, and $B$ some superset of that, for example $B=\{2,3,4\}$. Now we have $A \subseteq B$.

Then suppose we have a third set $C$ such that also $B \subseteq C$. Take for example $C=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

1. Can you see what the transitivity now claims about the relation between $A$ and $C$?
2. Can you see that the claim is indeed true for these particular three sets?
3. Can you see why the claim would be true for *any* three subsets $A,B,C$ of the base set?

Perhaps a final note of clarification. If you don't have $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, that's not a problem. Then transitivity is not claiming anything (about those three sets). It only steps in when you choose sets $A,B,C$ where the condition holds (that is, when you do have the subset relations from $A$ to $B$, and from $B$ to $C$). *Then* it steps in and says: "A-ha! I bet you have a relation between $A$ and $C$ too!"

Comment: Thank you but I fully understand it when it comes to 3 distinct sets A, B and C which you showed, however, for a power set its a lot more confusing to me. Could you show how P{1,2,3}={∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} is transitive? Elaborating on what I meant before. If the P{1,2,3} is transitive then 1⊆2, 1⊆3 and 1⊆3 but that is not the case and for transitivity to hold in the power set case: A⊆B and B⊆C, then A⊆C holds

Comment: You are still not using set braces like I suggested. Also please re-read the final clarification in my answer. Transitivity does not claim that $\{1\} \subseteq \{2\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am supposed to be using set braces or curly brackets because I am still confused by it. Please tell me how P{1,2,3}={∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} is transitive

Comment: I suggest you read my answer. What part of it is not clear?

Comment: I don't understand how P{1,2,3}={∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} is transitive when we don't have A⊆B and B⊆C!

Comment: Try concentrating on the word **if**. Transitivity is saying that **if** $A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, **then** $A \subseteq C$. It is not claiming that all three subset relations hold always. Try picking some three subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ where the first two relations are true. Do you see that **then** the third one is true also?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? What do you mean by 'where the first two relations are true'?  Say I pick {1,2},{1,3},{2,3}